# How to get VALUE by KEY in Json?

Tags: sql, json, jsonpath, zabbix

Given:

```
 [{"{#NAME}":"BULL","{#VALUE}":"98.03"},{"{#NAME}":"BILL","{#VALUE}":"98.32"}]
```

How get VALUE by NAME ?

My code didn't working :(

```
$['{#NAME}']['VALUE']
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Could you please clarify the question and specify the language you are using? Also, please add a snippet of the code and the error you got!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using the JSONPath preprocessing, the correct filter is `$['{#NAME}']`.

You can use https://jsonpath.com/ to do your tests since Zabbix doesn't have a similar feature (yet).